# Use third party composer packages in TYPO3 extensions

Tags: push-notification, typo3, extbase, service-worker, web-push

I have integrated a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/) for receiving Push Notifications in my TYPO3 Extension.

Now I want so send Messages form backend to the clients [web-push-php Library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php).

But how it is possible to integrate the library and its dependencies to TYPO3?

Comment: May I suggest to edit your question‘s title to match the subject better and improve visibility? Something like "Use third party composer packages in TYPO3 extensions"?

Comment: thanks a lot for changing title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up your project with composer you can just require `minishlink/web-push` and start using class `Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush`.

In case you‘re running in "legacy" mode (i.e. classic install without composer) or want to support both you‘ll need a different approach. IMO best practice is bundling composer requirements in `.phar` files - this way you can keep your IDE clean and your VCS footprint small. There‘s a blog post with a detailed description about [phar bundling in TYPO3 extensions](http://insight.helhum.io/post/148112375750/how-to-use-php-libraries-in-legacy-extensions). 
This method works for most composer requirements following PSR-0 or PSR-4 and should be viable in your case as `minishlink/web-push` seems to follow PSR-4.

You can even advance this by using scripts you can launch by running `composer run <script>` in your extension‘s root folder. TYPO3 extension `typo3_console` holds a [`composer.json`](https://github.com/helhum/typo3_console/blob/master/composer.json) defining such scripts.

If you need to run your extension in a TYPO3 6.2 environment you‘ll need to remove composer.json from extension folder as 6.2 fails coping with ["real composer requirements"](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/54491) (i.e. non-TYPO3-extension packages).